# С#. Получение всех дней указанного месяца

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте. 
Мне нужно получать все дни указанного месяца в виде коллекции дней, у каждого дня мне нужно знать его число и название.
Думал это делается в классе Calendar. Но похоже он не для этого).

> Псевдокод:

```
var days= GetDayOnMonth("Jun");

foreach(var day in days)
{
  day.Name    //название дня (понедельник)
  day.Number  //число (10)
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var year = 2017;
var month = 2;
var startDay = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
var endDay = startDay.AddMonths(1);
for (var date = startDay; date != endDay; date = date.AddDays(1))
    Console.WriteLine($"Number: {date.Day}, day of week: {date.DayOfWeek}");
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! То- что надо.

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

```
int year = 2017, month = 2;
int daysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

for (int day = 1; day <= daysCount; ++day) {
    string dayName = new DateTime(year, month, day).ToString("dddd");
    Console.WriteLine("Number = {0}, Name = {1}", day, dayName);
}
```